# How to create our own Cocoapod for a static library?

Tags: ios, github, deployment, static-libraries, cocoapods

I have developed a static library in iOS objective C, I want to upload it on Github so that the users are able to integrate it in their projects with Cocoapods. I have banged my head over it for a long time but with dissatisfying results. Following are the links I have tried:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/developing-static-library-for-ios-with-cocoapods/

Following are the errors I am encountering at one point or the other:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] The `source_files` pattern did not match any file

- [!] The specified path `GhazalahKhan/Pyze/Pyze.podspec` does not point to an existing podspec file.

- warning: Could not find remote branch 0.0.1 to clone.
- fatal: Remote branch 0.0.1 not found in upstream origin
```

Could anyone please suggest a tutorial with step by step explanation or write one himself? I will be really thankful.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should not be asking for tutorials here - you should ask   questions about specific problems instead. If you were to provide your `Podfile` and link to github repo, people might be able to help you resolve your errors.

Comment: Thanks, This is my podspec file: Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name= "Pyze”
s.version= "0.0.1"
s.summary= "A short description of Pyze."
s.description = “Blah blah blah blah” s.homepage = "https://github.com/******/*****” s.license= 'MIT'
s.author= { “*****” => “*****@kayosys.com” }
s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/*******/*****.git", :tag => 0.0.1 }
s.platform= :ios, '7.0'
s.requires_arc = true
s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/*.{h,m}'
s.resource_bundles = {
 'Pyze' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  } s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/*.h' s.frameworks = 'CoreLocation', 'MobileCoreServices'
end

Comment: and I am getting this error: - ERROR | [iOS] The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.

Comment: Please edit your question and properly format your Podfile - it is not readable in comments..